# SUSY 2 off-canvas and fixed

Tags: css, sass

Using Susy 2, is there a way to combine a fixed position sidebar that can also be triggered on and off canvas when viewed at smaller sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! Do it the same way you would without Susy, but use Susy for the math. Since the off-canvas bar will not be floated, you probably want to use the `span` function (instead of the mixin):

```
.off-canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: span(3);

  &.off {
    transform: translateX(- span(3));
  }
}
```

Something like that. There would be various ways to set is up — then use Susy for the widths.

Comment: I'm really beginning to see SUSY isn't just a grid. I'll have to create an example and post here for others.

Comment: Exactly! Susy can help with grids (and has a lot of grid shortcuts built in) — but it's really a set of math/layout helpers that you can use to create anything you want.